# Docker on Mac doesn't show all options when clicking on Whale icon

Tags: docker, macos, menu, tray

I have a problem in my Docker. Whenever I click on the whale icon, it shows a limited number of options instead of showing all options (like opening the Dashboard and Preferences for example).

I would like some help to solve this problem.

Docker Desktop
4.5.0 (74594)
MacOs Monterey 12.2.1

iMac 2019 Intel Core i5 chip

***My Docker menu***

[image: My Docker options in system tray]

***Docker menu I would like***

[image: Docker menu I would like]

Answer (score 0):

Seems fixed in version 4.6.0 (75818).

Comment: I went to the Docker repository and managed to find an issue that contained the problem and I've fixed it. Thanks